# How to use Material UI in react version 16.5.2

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, twilio

I am trying to use Material UI select in react version 16.5.2 However I am unable to use useState since that hook can only be used by react 16.8.0 and above.

Is there any way to use Material UI select in 16.5.2 without using useState?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { withTaskContext } from "@twilio/flex-ui";
import { selectCurrentEntity } from "../helpers/channelIntegrationFramework";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

class VoiceCallComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      functionsBaseUrl: this.props.functionsBaseUrl,
      settingsBaseUrl: this.props.settingsBaseUrl,
    };    

    this.init();
  }

  init = () => {
    console.log(
      `Connector: -- VoiceCallComponent -- functionsBaseUrl: ${this.state.functionsBaseUrl} -- settingsBaseUrl: ${this.state.settingsBaseUrl}`
    );
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Connector: ====== render ========");
    const [disposition, setDisposition] = useState("");
    console.log("disposition :- ", { disposition });
    const { task } = this.props;
    return (
      <div class="Twilio-TaskInfoPanel-default css-18ljn0d">
        <span class="Twilio" />
        <h1>Notes:</h1>
        <ul>
          <TextField
            style={{
              textAlign: "left",
              margin: "0px",
              width: "250px",
              height: "55px",
            }}
            hintText="Message Field"
            floatingLabelText="Note"
            multiline
            rows={2}
            maxRows={5}
            value={this.state.callnotes}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <p style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}></p>
          <label style={{ fontWeight: "700" }}>Disposition*: </label>

          <FormControl fullWidth>
            <InputLabel id="disposition-label">Disposition*:</InputLabel>
            <select
              labelId="disposition-label"
              id="disposition-select-label"
              value={disposition}
              onChange={handleSelectChange}
              fullWidth
            >
              <MenuItem value={"11"}>Contacted</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"22"}>Bad Number</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"33"}>Hung up on Call</MenuItem>
            </select>
          </FormControl>
</div>
);
}
}

export default withTaskContext(VoiceCallComponent);
```

The above code is throwing error since I am not using react version 16.8.0.